# css: расположение элементов снизу вверх с использованием flex

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Подскажите, как правильно настроить блок, чтобы можно было расположить элементы с 1 по N снизу вверх:

```css
.objects {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='objects'>
  <div class='object'>первый</div>
  <div class='object'>второй</div>
</div>
```

Но при таких стилях блоки выводятся снизу вверх (всё ок), но блок `первый` оказывается в самом низу, а `второй` - выше.

А хотелось бы наоборот - чтобы в самом низу был `второй`, а над ним `первый`.

Как это можно правильно реализовать без дополнительных блоков и т.п.?

Comment: `flex-direction: column;` - сделает в колонку в прямом порядке `flex-direction: column-reverse;` - в обратном порядке

Comment: @ВладимирКарманов, но это не поможет их разместить снизу-вверх буз изменения порядка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для такого подойдёт свойство `justify-content: flex-end` вместо `flex-direction: column-reverse`. (`justify-content` выравнивает по вертикали, `align-items` выравнивает по горизонтали)

```css
.objects {
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='objects'>
  <div class='object'>первый</div>
  <div class='object'>второй</div>
</div>
```

Comment: О, прикольно. А я бы через margin сделал :)

Answer (score 3):

```css
html, body, .objects {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.objects {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.object:first-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='objects'>
  <div class='object'>первый</div>
  <div class='object'>второй</div>
</div>
```